# same multiple jar in build path , will make problems?

Tags: java

I have a project name: examplePrj.
This projects contains 3 jar (which includes in the build path of examplePrj)
the 3 jars are: A.jar, B.jar, C.jar

1. Let say that A.jar and B.jar contains tbd.jar.
   And we said that examplePrj contains A.jar and B.jar
   Does tbd.jar will be included twise ?
   Is there any influence on the performance ?
2. Same as Q1, but in addition the project examplePrj contains the tbd.jar (total 3 includes)

?

Comment: What purpose does putting `tbd.jar` inside another jar serve? The classes inside it won't be found by the standard classloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note here is that classes inside the JARs are loaded by the classloader.

Now considering that tbd.jar has same classes inside it, Oracle will load these classes only once. The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the directories in the order they appear in the class path variable.

Comment: If `tbd.jar` contains class file(s), and `A.jar` contains `tbd.jar`, and you use (say) `javac` with `A.jar` (but not `tbd.jar`) in the classpath, the class file(s) in `tbd.jar` will **not** be found/loaded by the standard classloader.